Is there a way to delete this fine white line I have on the top of a website, after deciding not using a header?
I'm designing this website www.rikmerchie.com in Wordpress (with the Extendable theme) using the original design library (i'm not using elementor or plugins like that).
The thing is we decided we don't want a Header because is a one landing page and my client wants it very clean. But I keep seeing that fine white line on top, in all the website. Also in mobile.
The Header editor section is completely blank but I cannot delete it (or I don't know how)
I tried a few codes from Chat gpt to hide it, but it didn't work.
Please if somebody could guide me I would be forever grateful. Thanks!!

You can fix this issue by adding the following CSS code:
header.wp-block-group.has-background-background-color.has-background.is-layout-flow.wp-block-group-is-layout-flow.wp-container-1.is-position-sticky {
    border-bottom-width: 0px !important;
}

To apply this:

Go to Appearance > Customize in your WordPress dashboard.
Navigate to Additional CSS.
Paste the code above and click Publish.

